# Latex date datetime calculation month day year

Tags: date, datetime, latex, calculation

In Latex it´s possible to renew the date command in different formats and to take the language into account but I couldn´t find how you calculate with the date parts like \the\day+1 in Latex.

```
\leadingzero{\month}/\the\year -> \leadingzero{\month}[+4]/\the\year[-1]
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`advdate` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/advdate) has built-in conditions to deal with the advancement (forward or backward) or date components. Specifically, `\AdvMonth{<num>}` and `\AdvYear{<num>}` can be used to adjust the month and year from `\today`.

Here's an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{advdate}

\begin{document}

\today

\AdvMonth{4}\AdvYear{-1}

\today

\end{document}
```

Consider the order of advancement. It's better to advance from least to most significant date component; that is, day, then month, then year, since day advancement may have to consider leap years.

One can also set `\today` to some fixed date using `\SetDate{dd/mm/yyyy}`.